# Sum and order nested List<double>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to Sum() a List of accumulated doubles values - the list is inside another List.

This is the Object that has my List of accumulated double values

```
public class Something
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Company {get; set;}
        public List<double> AccumulatedResults { get; set; }
    }
```

The class "something" is then added to another list.

```
var listOfSomething = new List<Something>();

foreach(var item in anotherList)
{
    listOfSomething.Add(item);
}
```

Now i want to order listOfSomething by the list called AccumulatedResults. I have come up with this - but it's not working obviously

```
var topResults = listOfSomething.GroupBy(g => g.Id).SelectMany(s => s.OrderByDescending(d => d.Result.Sum())).Take(10).ToList();
```

**Solution:**
This code did the trick - thanks!

```
var topResults = listOfResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.AccumulatedResults.Sum());
```

Comment: I assume listOfSomething is a List<List<double>>? I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: listOfSomething is a list of the class in the top, called Something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order your the objects of `Something` in the list just by the sum up their `AccumulatedResults` as value to order by:

```
listOfSomething.OrderBy(S => S.AccumulatedResults.Sum()));
```

Comment: Big thanks, this one did the trick. Sometimes you just need another eye i guess :). 

Will accept this as soon as it's possible.